# Heroku Bad Request when trying to submit API requests from fton end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

It seems to be an issue actually connecting to the backend, the message in the error is blank:

```
Login.js:21          POST https://XXXX.herokuapp.com/users/login 400 (Bad Request)
onClick @ Login.js:21
De @ react-dom.production.min.js:54
Ue @ react-dom.production.min.js:54
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:55
Dr @ react-dom.production.min.js:105
Or @ react-dom.production.min.js:106
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:117
$l @ react-dom.production.min.js:273
Be @ react-dom.production.min.js:52
Hr @ react-dom.production.min.js:109
Qt @ react-dom.production.min.js:74
qt @ react-dom.production.min.js:73
Login.js:34 {message: {…}}
Login.js:43 Request Failed TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'customerAccessToken')
    at Login.js:36:42
```

Would really appreciate anyones help!

Comment: where is the `Login.js` ??? Can you share at least line 36? something in there is undefined but that is defined in your local. what is it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you - you made me realise I didn't have the values in my .env file as values in the congif vars in heroku - thats fixed it!